# which free antivius is best Comodo Antivirus and ClamWin AV

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, anti-virus

i have question about antivirus on servers

i was searcing all the day and found two antivirus with good comments on internet

Comodo Antivirus and ClamWin AV

also in real time protection, i think this option is not available in ClamAV

Thanks

Comment: Which is best for your situation will depend largely on what your specific requirements are. Also, last I knew ClamWin didn't do real time scanning. But it's been a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, ClamAV does not do real time protection, however it will run on Windows Server. I've not used Comodo, but on there spec page it states it only works on XP, Vista and 7, not Server OS's. There are very few free antivirus's that will run on a server OS.